# How to secure my laravel Rest application

Tags: laravel, api, security, passport.js

Hello i have develop a rest api with laravel and passport..How can i know if my application is secure ? The apis i think are secured because i use the token from passport and with every request i have to send my token to access the data.I am asking this question because i found that if someone type the url lets say myserver/env , he can see the env file with all the data (database connection).From htaccess i block it but i am asking here if i have to do more than that to secure it.Thanks for your time !!

Answer (score 0):

First, You should not give everyone read access to your .env file. You should restrict access so only the server can execute that file `0111`.

Second, in your `.htaccess` add this:

```
<Files .env>
  Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Third, how is the file even accessible by URL? The public folder should be the mapped directory.

For Reference: [How to secure .env file in laravel using file permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352541/how-to-secure-env-file-in-laravel-using-file-permission)

Comment: Thanks for your response..My htaccess have the code that you post ... So when i try to see the env file the server return forbiden and i have also disable the listing directory so when i try to see public folder i see an empty page....I believe its ok right?I can access the server from the api with all the data i need..

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a folder called `public` which is the only folder that needs to be pointed to your virtual host. The other folders should not be public and this is how your config files including the `.env` file will be kept secret.

An example of a Nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com/my_laravel_app/public; # Here we pointed the host example.com to the laravel's public folder

    index index.php;
    ...
```

More about deploying a Laravel app:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/deployment

And here's a good talk at Laracon EU about securing Laravel apps:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGGVGiq2y8